# removing downward arrow from css dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to alter a CSS drop down menu, and I am unable to remove a black arrow that appears when one of the sections unfolds.

there is an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/41r0eo1w/

here is some of the CSS:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
color: black;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
border-top: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
background: white;
box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 300;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
position: relative;
```

its the black, flat downward pointing arrow that appears when you click on the "Lookbook" section

What is creating this arrow? I cannot find anything in the CSS sheet that refers to it, is it part of the jQuery animation?

ideally I would have a pure white menu without any symbols at all.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick solution is to comment following lines whcih creates the triangle:

```
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  /*
  border-top: 13px solid #151515;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  */
  left: 0;
  bottom: -12px;
  bottom: -1px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/41r0eo1w/2/)

Answer (score 1):

That arrow is part of the link inside the first element of the dropdown, `#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a::before`.  The borders and background together [create a triangle](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).